# Problems after disabling hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation

In this example I have disabled hyphenation with `\hyphenchar\font=-1`, but there are words that 'get out of line'. Is there a way force latex to jump them to the next line ? And maybe still keep a decent justify ..

```
\documentclass {book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=210mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\hyphenchar\font=-1 % no hyphenation

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

I saw an example in a book, they might have used the space between characters in words instead of space between words.

Comment: `\raggedright`. But what's the reason for disabling hyphenation? By the way, `\hyphenchar\font=-1` is not the best way, because words in boldface or italics could still be hyphenated.

Comment: @egreg No, I still want a fully justified text, and I have seen examples like this

Comment: the reason is that I am using a language for which babel doesnt have hyphenation rules [maybe I'll go back to that] which creates many problems. And besides I find text with no hyphenation better.

Comment: If you are using a language for which the `babel` package doesn’t (yet) provide hyphenation patterns, load the package with the `nohyphenation` option (or more generally, set the current language to `nohyphenation`); as @egreg has already remarked, `\hyphenchar\font = -1` is not the proper way to go.

Comment: @GuM would that be something like `\usepackage[english.nohyphenation]{babel}`?

Comment: @alfred: Sorry, I made a mistake: the name of the pseudo-language with no hyphenation patterns is `nil`, not `nohyphenation`.  So, you should say `\usepackage[nil]{babel}`.  Note that this will simply suppress hyphenation (in a *much* more reliable way than the `\hyphenchar\font = -1` trick), it will *not* resolve the spacing issues.  I agree with other users of this site that your simultaneous request for (a) no hyphenation, (b) full justification, and (c) even interword spacing is simply impossible to honor.  See also the first quotation at the end of Chapter 14 of _The TeXbook_. :-)

Comment: You *can* use `nohyphenation` as the argument of a `hyphenrules` environment, though.

Comment: @gum thanks, `\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}` works. I also found an 'incantation' in https://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/gregorio/gregorio.pdf p8 `\makeatletter \chardefl@bahasa=255 \makeatother`. I think I will start another question to address properly my hyphenation problem.